# Can't put .mov file in iMovie

Tags: imovie

I'm trying to drag a .mov file into iMovie from Finder, but nothing happens when I try to drop it into the videos/images section. How do I put it in iMovie so I can edit it?

Comment: does it turn green with large Plus sign as you hover over iMove ? If not try moving around till it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to drag the .mov file into iMovie without any problems, so I'm wondering to where within iMovie you're actually trying to drag it?

Perhaps the best bet is to use the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> shortcut to open the Import window. Once open, use that to navigate to your video file and import it.